# C# Magento API Prices

Tags: c#, api, magento, attributes, product

Is there anyway to call catalogProductList and have it return the prices along with the other default product data in one call? Or, do I have to make "n" number of catalogProductInfo calls on each product individually? In my case, if I call catalogProductList, it returns over 1000 products and then I am having to do a catalogProductInfo on each of the over 1000 products which just breaks the program from having over 1000 API calls.

Comment: Besides rewriting the wsdl.xml and V2.php files?

Answer (score 0):

I was tasked with something similar from my company.  We were unable to find a way to easily grab the prices for all items.  The only way we've found to grab prices was to call `catalogProductInfo` 'n' times like you stated.  We are planning on simply extending the Magento API to provide methods for pulling/updating this data.